# VSCode で Intel コンパイラのエラーメッセージ向けに problemMatcher を書こうとしているがマッチしてくれない

Tags: 正規表現, vscode

VSCode の Remote Development Extension で、Windows 10 上 の VSCode から Linux サーバにアクセスして開発しています。

サーバ上には Intel のコンパイラがあり、これのエラーメッセージを VSCode で読み取ろうとしていますが、一つも検知できません。

エラーメッセージは今のところ2形式見かけています。

- エラーコードのないタイプ:

  ```
  src/Data.cpp(163): error: class "Node" has no member "local_index_"
  ```
- エラーコードのあるタイプ:

  ```
  src/Data.cpp(82): error #308: member "Node::m_" (declared at line 56 of "include/Node.h") is inaccessible
  ```

これに対して、vscodeのタスク定義の中で、以下のようにproblemMatcherを書いてみていますが、これで一件も検出されません。何がいけない・足りないのでしょうか?

ドキュメントは [Defining a problem matcher | Tasks in Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks#_defining-a-problem-matcher) を見ながら挑戦しています。

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: make all",
            "command": "make",
            "args": [
                "all",
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": {
                "fileLocation":"relative",
                "pattern": {
                    "regexp": "^([^(]+)\\(\\d+\\):\\s+(warning|error)( #\\d+)?:\\s+(.*)$",
                    /* 以下もダメでした */
                    /* "regexp": "^(.*)\\(\\d+\\):\\s+(warning|error)( #\\d+)?:\\s+(.*)$", */
                    /* "regexp": "^([-/._A-Za-z0-9]+)\\(\\d+\\):\\s+(warning|error)( #\\d+)?:\\s+(.*)$", */
                    "file": 1,
                    "line": 2,
                    "severity": 3,
                    "message": 5
                }
            },
            "group":{
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: こんな感じでしょうか？ `^(.+?)\\((\\d+)\\):\\s+(warning|error)( #\\d+)?:\\s+(.*)$` こちら [regexper](https://regexper.com/) のサイトで各バックスラッシュが二重になっているのを一重にして試してみました。

Answer (score 1):

kunif さんのコメントに答えの核心がありました。

私の書いていたものでは、 "(123)" のように、かっこで囲まれた行数の部分を "\(\d+\)" というパターンでとらえようとしていました。

しかし、これではあとで数字の部分をマッチした部分文字列（なんて言うんでしたっけ）として取り出せません。取り出せるようにするには、部分文字列の目印のためのカッコが必要なので "\((\d+)\)" と書く必要があったのでした。

目に見えるかっこのことは気にしていましたが見えない方のかっこを忘れておりました。

おかげで通るようになりました！